# How to change SharePoint 2013 site template like Team site to developer site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013 ,I had created top level site as Team site now i want to switch over to team site into Developer site in SharePoint Enterprise server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to change the site template after you create the site. Take a look at this thread, though it is for SharePoint 2010 version:

[How do you switch to a different site template in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23492/how-do-you-switch-to-a-different-site-template-in-sharepoint-2010)

But up till now there is no update on this for SharePoint 2013. Once you create the site, you cannot update its template. You need to create the new site with different template.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I try to Run SharePoint Hosted app there was an Error : so i need page "App in Testing" where this will be?

Comment: For testing the app you need to create the developer site first then you might not get the error.

Comment: Please run the script in my answer below

Answer (score 6):

You can enable developer feature by running the below script in the browser console:

```
'use strict';
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
var site = context.get_site();
context.load(site);
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
  site.get_features().add('e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085', true, 0);
  context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    alert('added the developer site feature to the site collection!');
  }, function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
    alert('unable to add the developer site feature to the site collection: ' + args);
  });
}, function (sender, args) {
  alert('oops! ' + args);
});
```

This will enable the hidden developer feature and add the missing lists and libraries. Even the Apps in Testing